# Expression blend 4 dynamic layout example

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, expression-blend

I am trying to play with making my app look better and I found this and was incredibly impressed with the workspace example found here: http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/ff624123.aspx look at the example with state timeline and props with the workspaces which switch what has focus in the window.

The code can be found here : http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/en-us/DynamicLayoutTrans

When i run the code that I download from above - it runs inside a web page however.

My App is an exe - can somebody help me pull apart all of this example code - to have just the workbench example in its own project that runs inside an exe instead of a web browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample you're pointing to is a Silverlight application, not WPF. In general you can often copy the files from a Silverlight project into a new WPF project and possibly fix a few compiler errors to make it available to your WPF app.

Comment: Its fixing the compilation errors which is catching me however. I think it would be easier to explain over an IM app or something. Available for that?